# jsonpickle - Wrong JSON format

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, jsonpickle

I'm trying to use jsonpickle to send an Object to front-end in JSON format.
Here is the code:

```
#some code here...
return render(
    request,
    'template.html',
    {   
        'json_values': jsonpickle.encode(values),          
    }
)
```

But, when I try to echo the string generated in my javascript code I'm getting this result when I call `console.log({{json_values}})`:

> [{'&quotid&quot: 7, &quotnovo_peso&quot: &quot13&quot}, {&quotid&quot: 13, &quotnovo_peso&quot: &quot17&quot}]

See the image below in console:
[image]

I'm using the last Google Chrome version.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: How is `json_values` handled in the template?

Comment: I'm just calling console.log ( {{ json_values }} ) so I will can handle the values. These values are an ID and a Weight as Number value that will be send to an endpoint via ajax.

Comment: I don't use django, but it looks like you want to turn off auto-escaping html for that part..  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape   so something like -> `console.log({% autoescape off %}{{json_values}}{% endautoescape %})`

Comment: It worked! Post as an answer please.